# Do I need EMI shielding for a 5V signal PCB placed beside high powered DC cable 48V 50A?

Tags: dc, emc, high-current, shielding

I have PCBs located just below the high-powered DC cable at 50A 48V.

My PCB has input-output from 5V signal cables from all over the place.

The 5V signals are for:

1. 12V and 5V Signal driving the EM relay open/close - Plain On and Off
2. Analog output from sensors to MCU - Analog Signal 0V-5V
3. Power from DC converter 5V to sensors - Power with a bit of ripple from DC converter
4. Driver controller communicating to another driver via 5V digital signal - Plain on and off

Questions

1. Should I shield my PCB with aluminum sheets or shield the DC cable
   instead?
2. How thick does the aluminum sheet need to be?

Comment: You need to add a lot more details for this to be answerable. What exactly is a "5V signal cable"? When it comes to EMC, it is usually better to think about currents rather than voltages. A current loop with 5V levels will probably work just fine even in rough environments, for example.

Comment: Hello Lundin, I added some details to the "5V Signal Cable" Is it clearer now?
The ampere should be quite low for this board

Comment: That only says what functions the signals have, not the nature of the actual signals, nor what drives them. As far as I can tell from the little info given, your whole system design is plain wrong.

Comment: Hello Lundin, can you help me explain what is the nature of the actual signal? so I know what kind of info I can provide?
I am pretty new here and not quite used to with what should I provide, this is my first question

Comment: What drives the signal? What form is it, plain on/off, pulse trains, PWM, some digital protocol and so on. From an EMC point of view it is mostly relevant to think of currents though - everything with high resistance/low currents is generally much more vulnerable to EMI.

Comment: Hello Lundin, thank you for your input again, I have added some details again according to your input. There is no digital protocol or PWM, it just plain on and off, and all devices is just giving voltage signal and there should be no current (Unless the 5V power line to sensor and EM relay)
Does it mean that my 5V power line will be affected by the EMI?

Comment: It's never a good idea to have 5V MCU pin signals etc to leave the PCB. It likely means that your whole product is vulnerable to EMI.

Comment: some of my signals is being used for driving a motor located far away from the MCU, so I need the signals to be outside the MCU going to the driver.
Some of the devices also need to be triggered by signal and located far from the MCU.
Will shielded cable able to do the job?

Comment: How exactly are you going to control a motor with a 5V signal from a MCU pin? Is it some tiny stepper motor or what?

Comment: the MCU will send PWM signal, Direction signal, and Enable signal to the Driver.
Driver will take another power source to run the motor with signal from MCU.
But in this question, the MCU is not in the picture, it is the signal mostly from the driver to control the relay and analog signal from sensors which will go to MCU

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on what functions your signal board performs.

Let's start with the fact that direct current does not have a skin effect, in addition, it does not have harmonics inherent in alternating current, so you should not be afraid of a serious effect. There will be no interference on your board.

What problems may arise:

1. Interruptions in the operation of reed switches and inductances.
2. Pickups on field-effect transistors, if they do not have a pull-down resistor in the circuit.

As I wrote earlier, direct current has no skin effect, so you can easily shield your power cable, providing good protection.

To protect individual board nodes, sensitive sensors to the electromagnetic field, it is enough to ground your signal board and provide individual nodes with screens.

Comment: Hello  Джон Смит, Thank you for the answer
I do not have reed switches, inductance, or FET on the board, the board is just a connection board + relay.  I am just afraid there will be induced voltage from the DC power cable that can give voltage noise to the 5V signal which might end up damaging the devices that receive it. Normally devices like this only tolerate +-0.5V from 5V.
I cannot find a reference for myself to read about this.

Comment: The relay is standard Relay like this https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1558263.pdf
which is operated on EM but I am not sure if it will be affected that much.

Comment: calvinglob, Electromagnetic relays at the moment of closing the contacts create much more interference, especially when a large current flows.

For peace of mind, you can easily check with an oscilloscope what kind of interference your power cable is creating.